# get all search result rather then just top for twitter widget

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using twitter widget like below.

```
<script src="//widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
            <script>
            new TWTR.Widget({
              version: 2,
              type: 'search',
              search:'#xxx',
              rpp: 10,
              interval: 1000,
              title: 'Recent Tweets ',
              width: 234,
              height: 330,
              theme: {
                shell: {
                  background: 'none',
                  color: '#555555'
                },
                tweets: {
                  background: 'none',
                  color: '#666',
                  links: '#01972e'
                }
              },
              features: {
                scrollbar: true,
                loop: false,
                live: true,
                hashtags: true,
                timestamp: true,
                avatars: true,
                behavior: 'all'
              }
            }).render().start();
            </script>
```

This gives me only top results rather then all. If I go to my twitter account and search for #xxx I get three tweets under top result and a lot more under view all. Those three under the top result are the one I am getting when using the code above.

I have tried to look into the documented widget.js but didn't find the option for this.

Comment: I tried helping you, but looking at your code I see you are pulling tweets from porn, and it disturbs me :(

Comment: @defau1t ohh apologies if xxx made you think this, But I tried to put xxx as example here :)

Comment: NO not that check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NHGnK/

Comment: my bad, I should have put any other alphabet there. Tend to put xxx as masking the words. Anyway I sorted it out it seems to be a problem with safe mode.